# How can I keep the indentation between lines?

Tags: python

I'm writing a new app in python and I need to keep indentation between lines.

I have this code from a file:

```
line 1
   __LINE TO CHANGE__
line 3
```

and I'd like to get:

```
line 1
   added code line a
   added code line b
line 3
```

I have tried some solutions, adding \n, \n\r, usign """ """ string, string("") but I got only this two results:

```
line 1
    added code line a added code line b
line 3


line 1
    added code line a
added code line b
line 3
```

I'm using replace() function to change a line.

Thanks

EDITED:
My code:

```
Reading from file and put into variable named code:
line 1
    __LINE TO CHANGE__
line 3

text = "added code line a"
text += "added code line b" 

available_pos = ["__LINE TO CHANGE__"]
text_to_add = [text]

code = code.replace(available_pos, text_to_add)
```

Comment: so where is your code ?

Comment: Do you mean like extending a line of code using the backslash?

Comment: `"foo".replace("foo","   "+"foo")`

Comment: @paganu add your code to question body !

Comment: so you want to replace line 2 with two new lines?

Comment: When reading the file, determine the number of spaces or tabs used to indent the __LINE TO CHANGE__, then add that same number to the beginning of the "added code line b"?

Comment: It's what I looking for, but I don't know how I can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

INDENT_RE = re.compile(r'^\s*$')

def matching_indent(line, pattern):
    """
    Returns indent if line matches pattern, else returns None.
    """
    if line.endswith(pattern):
        indent = line[:-len(pattern)]
        if INDENT_RE.match(indent):
            return indent
    return None

def replace_line(lines, pattern, replacements):
    for line in lines:
        indent = matching_indent(line, pattern)
        if indent is None:
            yield line
        else:
            for replacement in replacements:
                yield indent + replacement
```

You can use it like this:

```
code = '''line 1
    __LINE TO CHANGE__
line 3'''

print('\n'.join(replace_line(
    code.split('\n'),                           # one string per line
    '__LINE TO CHANGE__',                       # the string to replace
    ["added code line a", "added code line b"]  # the strings to replace with
)))
```

The output:

```
line 1
    added code line a
    added code line b
line 3
```

You can also use this with a file, by doing something like:

```
with open("input") as f:
    print(''.join(replace_line(f, 'some pattern\n', ['foo\n', 'bar\n'])))
```

Note that here I've added a `'\n'` to the ends of the pattern and replacements. If you intend on using this with the output of `readlines` (which includes a `\n` at the end of each line) then you may want to adjust the function to expect them and do this for you.

Comment: your functions matching_indent and replace_line It what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() # get all lines
    lines[1] = "    added code line a\n    added code line b\n" #reassign second line in lines 
    with open("in.txt","w") as f1: # overwrite the file with updated content
        f1.writelines(lines)
```

`"    added code line a\n    added code line b\n"` writes on two lines indented four spaces

To replace based on certain criteria, use enumerate and an if check:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for ind, line in enumerate(lines):
        if "whatever" in line:
           lines[ind] = "   added code line a\n   added code line b\n"
    with open("in.txt","w") as f1:
        f1.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: yes, but I don't know always indentation and where find the exact line

Comment: well just enumerate over lines, if line is one to replace, replace it using the index then write

Comment: yes, but can be more complicated, I post an example

Comment: you have to know what lines you want to change or at the very least the index so the code posted gives you your expected output so beyond that is is hard to do any more

Answer (score 0):

Another example with html tags, 3 parts to change read from a file template.html and put into template var

```
<div>
   <div>
        ___MENU___
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    ___CONTENT___
</div>
<div>
    ___BOTTOM___
</div>
```

Next I change three parts with code like:

```
html = "<p>"
hrml += "   HELLO WORLD"   
html += "</p>"
```

and so on with others two text to replace.

```
available_pos = ["___MENU___", "___CONTENT___", "___BOTTOM___"]
text_to_add = [html, html1, html2]
```

template = template.replace(available_pos, text_to_add)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what specific character is used to indent (space, tab, etc...) or how many are used to indent, then you need to get that from the original line that you read from the file, then use that to precede your new line. I'm going to borrow & add to Padraic's response:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for ind, line in enumerate(lines):
        num_of_chars = len(line) - len(line.lstrip()) # Get the preceding characters.
        new_line = line[:num_of_chars] + "added code line a" # Add the same to the new line.
        lines[ind] = new_line
```